# Get temp path with file name

Tags: c++

I want to get path to file like this > **%ENV%/%FILE_NAME%.docx**

But c++ doesn't make sense at all and nothing works..
I would use std::string but it's not compatible so I tried multiple ways of converting it to char[] or char* but none of them works and I'm also pretty sure this is unsafe..

> **My code so far (I know it's the worst code ever..)**

```
char* appendCharToCharArray(char* array, char a)
{
    size_t len = strlen(array);

    char* ret = new char[len + 2];

    strcpy(ret, array);
    ret[len] = a;
    ret[len + 1] = '\0';

    return ret;
}

const char* getBaseName(std::string path)
{
    std::string base_filename = path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);

    std::string::size_type const p(base_filename.find_last_of('.'));
    std::string file_without_extension = base_filename.substr(0, p);

    return file_without_extension.c_str();
}

int main()
{
    char szExeFileName[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szExeFileName, MAX_PATH);

    const char* file_name = getBaseName(std::string(szExeFileName));

    char* new_file = getenv("temp");
    new_file = appendCharToCharArray(new_file, '\\');

    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(file_name)/sizeof(file_name[0]);i++)
    {
        new_file = appendCharToCharArray(new_file, file_name[i]);
    }

    new_file = appendCharToCharArray(new_file, '.');
    new_file = appendCharToCharArray(new_file, 'd');
    new_file = appendCharToCharArray(new_file, 'o');
    new_file = appendCharToCharArray(new_file, 'c');
    new_file = appendCharToCharArray(new_file, 'x');

    std::cout << new_file << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Zero `goto`s, so no, this isn't the worst code ever.

Comment: You should expand on why `std::string` is not compatible. My experience is not only is it always compatible, it's almost always much easier.

Comment: Make sure you are not compiling the program for unicode. That'll mess up all of the use of `char` and `string`. You'll have to use `wchar` and `wstring`.

Comment: GetMOduleFileName - returns char[]
getenv - return char[]
and I also need file_name to be char[] for further functions

Comment: A bug: `std::string file_without_extension` is a local variable. It expires at the end of the function taking the array returned at `return file_without_extension.c_str();` with it. Return the `string` instead.

Comment: Fun fact, MAX_PATH is probably much smaller than the maximum path length supported by Windows.  For relevant routines, they often follow the pattern of "give me a buffer for the file name, and length, and if the buffer isn't big enough I'll return an error code and tell you how big the buffer needed to be".  q.v. MSDN [maximum file path limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `appendCharToCharArray()` is just horribly inefficient in general, and also you are leaking lots of memory with the way you are using it.  Just use `std::string` instead.  And yes, you *can* use `std::string` in this code, it is perfectly "compatible" if you use it correctly.

`getBaseName()` is returning a `char*` pointer to the data of a local `std::string` variable that goes out of scope when the function exits, thus a dangling pointer is returned.  Again, use `std::string` instead.

And, you should use the Win32 `GetTempPath/2()` function instead of `getenv("temp")`.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string getBaseName(const std::string &path)
{
    std::string base_filename = path.substr(path.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);

    std::string::size_type const p(base_filename.find_last_of('.'));
    std::string file_without_extension = base_filename.substr(0, p);

    return file_without_extension;
}

int main()
{
    char szExeFileName[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, szExeFileName, MAX_PATH);

    char szTempFolder[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, szTempFolder);

    std::string new_file = std::string(szTempFolder) + getBaseName(szExeFileName) + ".docx";

    std::cout << new_file << std::endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r4GY7fxYT)

That being said, the Win32 Shell API has functions for manipulating path strings, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

int main()
{
    char szExeFileName[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, szExeFileName, MAX_PATH);

    char szTempFolder[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, szTempFolder);

    char new_file[MAX_PATH] = {};
    PathCombineA(new_file, szTempFolder, PathFindFileNameA(szExeFileName));
    PathRenameExtensionA(new_file, ".docx");

    std::cout << new_file << std::endl;
}
```

Or, if you are using C++17 or later, consider using `std::filesystem::path` instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <windows.h>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    char szExeFileName[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, szExeFileName, MAX_PATH);

    char szTempFolder[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetTempPathA(MAX_PATH, szTempFolder);

    fs::path new_file = fs::path(szTempFolder) / fs::path(szExeFileName).stem();
    new_file += ".docx";

    // alternatively:
    // fs::path new_file = fs::path(szTempFolder) / fs::path(szExeFileName).filename();
    // new_file.replace_extension(".docx");

    std::cout << new_file << std::endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j9fj383b5)